# Relationships by _id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have been studying MongoDb to migrate my project to `MEAN` technologies and I have in my database two collections `person` where I put all basic information like name, age, etc and `account` where I put information like email, pass, level. I need to create a relationship between that collections. What I did was set `account`'s _id equals to `person`' _id. Is that correct ?

Person Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569c39684e23c75303a0fe32"),
    "name" : {
            "First" : "Daniel Alessandro",
            "Last" : "Aguilar Chombo"
    },
    "area" : 1
}
```

Account Collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("569c39684e23c75303a0fe32"),
        "email" : "testAccount@live.com",
        "password" : "testPassword4218",
        "level" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$ref`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) may used here, to build the relationship between `User` and `Account`.

Take [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) as example:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  name    : { First: String, Last: String},
  area    : Number,
  account : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' }]
});

 var accountSchema = Schema({{
        email : String,
        password : String,
        level : Number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that would be a 1:1 relationship and I would ask why not having the data in one collection then.

You can however simply add a field (or array) of type `ObjectID` to one collection and store the `id_`s of the other collection. It *simulates* a classical foreign key relationship as we know it from RDBMS.

Comment: I know that in NoSql databases is not necessary to normalize or create relationships between collections, but I need to normalize this tables because I don't want to put that data (Email and pass) in the same document.